# Getting OpenGL function error when profiling but not when running

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, profiling

I have a cocos2d-iphone project. When I run the project on simulator I don't get any error. But if I try to profile it I get multiple errors in OpenGl functions found inside CCParticleSystemQuad.m file. To make it clearer I'm posting the snapshot of the error zone.
[image]

[Here's the link to the image in case you want to see it closely.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEBuk.png)

Do you have any clues?

Answer (score 0):

`offsetof` is a macro that resolves to an LLVM compiler builtin function. It's defined in `stddef.h`, but it's possible your project's headers don't include that file when building for a device.